# Probability Question Tournament Final

Tags: probability

If one team had a $26\%$ chance of winning a tournament and another had a $10\%$ of winning the tournament .. what would be the odds of both teams making it to the final match of the tournament?

I thought it would be $2(0.26)$ multiplied by $2(0.1)$ but that's not right.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the tournament structure? Single-elimination bracket? If so, then it could even be 0% depending on how they were seeded

Comment: It's a 24 team tournament with 16 teams making it into the single elimination bracket and assuming those teams are on opposite ends of the bracket.